# How to generate dynamic navigation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here is my categories table migration script from which I want to generate multilevel navigation.

Note: I am using "parent" column to generate multi-level menus.

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('title');
   $table->text('description');
   $table->string('icon');
   $table->tinyInteger('active')->default(1);
   $table->integer('sort')->default(0);
   $table->integer('views')->default(0);
   $table->integer('parent')->default(0);
   $table->timestamps();
   $table->softDeletes();
});
```

What is the best way to generate tree of main-menus, sub-menus and sub-sub-menus using minimum loops, usage in the views would be great and helpful?

The result I want to achieve should be following, it is three level deep for generating 3 level navigation.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Accessories
            [parent] => 0
            [sub_cats] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 29
                            [title] => Kids
                            [parent] => 1
                            [sub_cats] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 41
                                        [title] => Shirts
                                        [parent] => 29
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 42
                                        [title] => Toys
                                        [parent] => 29
                                    )
                            )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 30
                            [title] => Men
                            [parent] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 31
                            [title] => Women
                            [parent] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [title] => Cakes
            [parent] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be a question?

Comment: I know it is a basic question but if you can share the best way it would be beneficial for lot of newbies like me :-) Thanks

Comment: @HerrDerb is right.  You might want to add some more info, better explain your question, include some sample code ...  I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Okay guys, I will update my question in detail.

Comment: @HerrDerb I have updated my question, please answer the question I am stuck and need it asap. Thanks.

Comment: You should save children instead of parents. This way, you are able to implement one simple recursive methode in which you would feed your root and that will generate your desired (json) array

Comment: Is that hard to suggest me, how to generate above mentioned array? I have achieve the result just looking for best one.